# Mysql replication both way (bidirectional)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database-replication

I want to sync two DBs run time

server A: Amazon ec2 with Public IP and mysql installed.
Server B: this is private machine in LAN with mysql. (IP is private like 192.168 series)

So i tried multiple way with single public ip in this scene, no luck.
Is there any fetch/pull and Push we can do on AWS instance from local one.
Means AWS has unique IP so we can use it for pull and push data.
Is it possible such thing?

Also server B (local) can we use ISP's IP (IP got on 'what is my IP')
But ultimately there are 10 machine in LAN which all have same IP (ISP's IP)

So can be data pushed to AWS (server A) from local (Server B)
or can data pulled from AWS to local

This will help me a lot if goes right

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a standard mechanism for the connections used for replication: the slave server is always responsible for initiating, and holding open, the connection to the master, and the master uses that connection to push events to the slave.

When replication is circular, each machine is both master and slave, and therefore both need to be able to initiate a connection to each other.

In your configuration, the slave on the private network should be easily able to establish a connection to the master with a public IP address, but not the other way around, because of the private IP address.

The short answer, then, is that this is a problem that is solved by having the appropriate network infrastructure in place to enabled those connections -- specifically, a tunnel or VPN (and there is a large, but not total, overlap between those two terms).

Look into openvpn, or ssh tunneling.  If your EC2 machine is in VPC, VPC also offers hardware VPN solution.  There are many solutions, and not a single "correct" one, because, as I suggested above, this is not a MySQL-specific issue and MySQL does not have a built-in solution, since this is really a networking issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can achieve this but it will take a lot of configuring.
You need to do port forwarding on your private network to allow the MySQL traffic in to the machine hosting the server.

Then you will need to decide how you want the data to replicate, There are a few ways in [MySQL to do it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html)

Or you could try and write a script that does it but that might end up being more difficult. You need to think about what you are trying to achieve and if this is the best way to do it because it will require a lot of effort.

Comment: Any simple way among all these.
And any link for port forwarding

Comment: Link you gave shows lots replication. Frnakly more confused I am.
As per current scene which one you will suggest.

Comment: I cannot design solutions for you, I can give you the appropriate information you requested and you need to make your own decision and research the issues you will encounter doing this. You asked if this can be done and the answer is Yes.